# reading from several topics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to develop an application that takes four different topics from a kafka server and takes take specific actions with each topic.

I have created a class that receives a DStream and has a method that should transform the DStream.

For example, the handler class:

```
class StreamHandler(stream:DStream[String]) {
  val stream:DStream[String] = stream

  def doActions():DStream[String] =  {
    //Do smth. to DStream
  }
}
```

And now, imagine I call doActions() from the main class for each handler class I want, would it be repeated with each arriving DStream or only once?

```
val topicHandler1 = new StreamHandler(KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "myGroup", Map("topic1"->1)).map(_._2)
val topicHandler2 = new OtherStreamHandler(KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "myGroup", Map("topic2"->1)).map(_._2)

topicHandler1.doActions()
topicHandler2 .doActions()

ssc.start()
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I guess you want to say `topicHandler1.doActions()` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I misstyped that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformations declared on the `StreamHandler` will be applied to each batch of the DStream. The current code is quite incomplete to give you a certain answer. In the DStream transformation pipeline you will need an [action that materializes the DStream](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams), otherwise nothing will happen.

Regarding the approach, a function that takes a DStream and applies transformations to it would be sufficient and easy to test:

```
val pipeline:DStream[Data] => () = dstream => 
    dstream.map(...).filter(...).print()
```

As it stands, it doesn't look like the class construction is buying much.

Comment: Thanks. I have shortened the pieces of code to make it clearer.